# What is the right consistency for ghee?

Tags: butter, water, emulsion, ghee, filtering

Some of ghee I find in stores has liquid on top (with some solids floating about), while in other brands it is completely solid (both jars are stored at the same temperature). Also, the latter ghee (that doesn't split into a liquid layer on top) is often twice as expensive as the former.

So, what is the "right" texture/consistency for ghee? Are the more "solid" brands just better at filtering out the usual water and protein? Or, are there really some components of butterfat itself that melt at lower temperatures, only to get filtered out by the more "solid" ghee brands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghee is suppose to be 100% butter fat. The water has since been boiled off. If it has a liquid portion at room temperature this is either they did not remove all the water and solids that floated to the surface or an additive liquid or preservative did not set right (Most likely). I would avoid it if possible. If not, use your nose and make sure it is not gone rancid.

Answer (score -1):

When making ghee the solids [milk fats, salt] darken and go to the bottom and pure butterfat is poured off. There should not be liquids of any kind in pure ghee. It's not pure.

Comment: I don't believe the salt is going to come out of the fat when you make ghee. I'd suggest using unsalted butter. Also, what you want is to remove the water, not the liquid. Ghee will remain a liquid until it cools enough. It should be a mushy solid at room temperature which I think is what you mean.

Comment: I have Made ghee a number of times and I know what happens.At a certain point the milk solids and salt go to the bottom of the pan and start to become light brown when they are filtered out what you have is pure butter fat or ghee. Ghee is solid in the refrigerator and semi solid not in the refrigerator depending on the temperature.